# How to run a Service always in background (Non-Stop) - Android

Tags: android

I have created a `Service` in my android application which starts running on `BOOT_COMPLETE`. I want to run my `Service` non-stop (run always), and for that I have used `while(true)` inside `onStartCommand()` method. So is this fine to use `while(true)` or there is any other better way to run a service always in background?

**This is code of my Service:**

```
package com.example.abc.project1;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import org.json.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public class HelloService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "HelloService";
    private boolean isRunning  = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        isRunning = true;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    /*non-stop work to be done in background always*/
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would do `while(isRunning)`, but what is wrong with your current approach? Does it not work?

Comment: i think service keeps on running untill you call stopService() method or till you switch off the phone

Comment: All android services run until you explicitly call stopService or turn off the phone..

Comment: So what should I do for running service always in background? @CommonsWare

Comment: Add BroadcastReciever that listen for BOOT_COMPLETED state and inside OnRecieve() method call startService()

Answer (score 0):

[I have not tried](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/direct-boot.html) this myself but if you change receiver to service it should work.